# What is $g'(x)$ if $g(x) =x^2 \int_{x-2}^{\sin x} \cos^2t dt $?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, trigonometry

What is $g'(x)$ if $$g(x)= x^2 \int_{x-2}^{\sin x} \cos^2t dt?$$

So i get $g'(x) = 2x(\int_{x-2}^{sinx} cos^2t dt ) + x^2(cos^2(sinx)-cos^2(x-2))$ as my final answer. Is this right?, thanks. Use fundamental theorem of calculus and chain rule, product rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that the antiderivative of $\cos^2{t}$ is some function $G(t)$.  By the FTC:

$$g(x)=x^2 [G(\sin{x}) - G(x-2)]$$

Now take the derivative wrt $x$, recalling that $G'(x)=\cos^2{x}$.

Comment: It might be worth providing the general form from the FTC, as well, so that josh might better understand it.

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{f(x)}^{g(x)} h(x,t)dt = \int_{f(x)}^{g(x)} \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}dt + h(x,g(x))-h(x,f(x))
$$

Comment: @Ron Do you mean that $G'(t) = cos^2t$?

Comment: @GlenO: I chose not to do that, as I felt that my explanation was nice and simple.  Many times I feel it does not help to write more general formulae, as they may just complicate matters.

Comment: @josh: well, yes.  I wrote $x$ because $t$ was just the dummy integration variable.

Comment: Alright so i expanded and get $g(x) = x^G(sinx) - x^2G(x-2). Do i use chain rule?

Comment: @josh: absolutely!  That's the whole point of the problem.  Much easier than actually integrating and then taking the derivative, huh?

Comment: So i get $g'(x) = 2x(G(sinx)-G(x-2)) + x^2(cos^2(sinx)-cos^2(x-2))$ but what is G(x)?

Comment: @josh write $2x[G(sinx)-G(x-2)]=2g(x)/x$ .

Comment: "what is G(x)" ... it's defined so that $G(b)-G(a)=\int_a^b \cos x^2dx$.

Comment: $$\frac{d}{dx} G(\sin{x}) = \cos^2{(\sin{x})} \cos{x}$$

Comment: @josh You'll get your answer $g'$ in terms of $g$ anyway or you'll have to integrate it.

Comment: So i get $g'(x) = 2x(\int_{x-2}^{sinx} cos^2t dt ) + x^2(cos^2(sinx)-cos^2(x-2))$ as my final answer. Is this right?, thanks.

Comment: Yep!. ie. $g'=2g/x+x^2(cos^2(sin)-cos^2(x-2))$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What happens when you differentiate an integral?

Think of it like this: $g(x) = a(x)b(x)$ where $a(x) = x^2$ and $b(x) = \int\limits_{x-2}^{\sin(x)}cos^2(t)dt$

The FTC should help with $b(x)$ in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use chain rule and derivative of integral is computed like this:
$$f=\int_{\phi(x)}^{\psi(x)}g(t,x)dt$$
$$\dfrac{df}{dx}=\psi'(x)\times g(\psi)-\phi'(x)\times g(\phi)+\int_{\phi(x)}^{\psi(x)}\dfrac{d\ [ g(t,x)]}{dx}dt$$

Answer (score 0):

First I would break up the function as $$f(x)=x^2\cdot \left(\int_{x-2}^0 \cos^2(t)dt+\int_{0}^{\sin(x)} \cos^2(t)dt\right)=x^2\cdot \left(\int_{0}^{\sin(x)} \cos^2(t)dt-\int_{0}^{x-2}\cos^2(t)dt\right),$$ then just apply the product rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus along with the chain rule.